# "Could not get cmap table size!" occurs in flutter even when no external font is used

Tags: flutter, dart

When coding in flutter I had received the following error after using an external font:

```
[ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
```

After searching this, I had determined that it was my external font that I had previously used that was the culprit. I had soon removed the font, and I decided to use the default Roboto font given.

However, after running my program, the error had still occurred. I changed the emulator that I had used but the error had still occurred again.

Here is some info that you might need.

The main.dart file where the previous font family had been initialized. Keep in mind that the font-family setting had been commented out.

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Logs(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          //fontFamily: "Manrope"
        ),
        home: AllLogs(),
        routes: {
          '/addLog': (ctx) => AddLog()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml. Keep in mind, again, that I had commented out the region where my code for initializing the font had been.

```
name: track_your_day
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^3.2.0
  #fading_edge_scrollview: ^1.1.0
  #neumorphic: ^0.1.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
#  fonts:
#    - family: Manrope
#      fonts:
#        - asset: Fonts/manrope-regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Thank You for your support!

Comment: Also Have this Problem :(

Comment: yeah, i still don't know what happened and I eventually gave up on the project. Can you probably try and use a different font?

Comment: So I fixed the problem by removing the font totally. It would make my app crash on release! I ran `flutter clean`, then did a rebuild that seemed to work fine!

Comment: nice to know it works! I guess that might happen with certain fonts, but i don't know why...